# Taking value from array in JSON in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, json

I want to get value from first "low"(-5) from forecast but i got null errors. I did some researches but i couldn't find the answer. Examples are very complex.

```
 "item": {

     "forecast": [
      {
       "date": "7 Dec 2015",
       "day": "Mon",
       "high": "1",
       "low": "-5",
      },
      {
       "date": "8 Dec 2015",
       "day": "Tue",
       "high": "-2",
       "low": "-6",
      },

     ],
```

Item.java

```
private Forecast forecast;

    public Forecast getForecast() {
        return forecast;
    }
forecast=new Forecast();
        forecast.paupulate(data.optJSONObject("forecast[0]"));
```

Forecast.java

```
private int low;
    @Override
    public void paupulate(JSONObject data) {
        low=data.optInt("low");
    }
    public int GetLow(){
             return low;
        }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `forecast ` is a `JSONArray` instead `JSONObject`

Comment: error : "org.json.JSONObject in forecast can not be applied to org.json.JSONArray

Answer (score 0):

Your Pojo is treating the forecast json as an object but its an array

You need to change your pojo to -

```
private Forecast[] forecast;

public Forecast[] getForecast() {
    return forecast;
}
```

then in order to get the first low(-5) you do

```
Forecast[] forecasts = myItem.getForecast();
int requiredValue = forecasts[0].GetLow();
```

Comment: i will add them to Item.java, dont i? 

and when i did it, i got non-static error in this line:
 Forecast[] forecasts = Item.getForecast();

Comment: yes getForecast() is a non static method man, you need to have an instance of the item class first in order to use non static methods, you can see this tutorial to understand basics of java and oop http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/

Comment: sorry but i cant succedd it.

private static Forecast[] forecast;
public static Forecast[] getForecast() {
        return forecast;
    }
public void paupulate(JSONObject data) {
forecast=new Forecast();
        forecast.paupulate(data.optJSONObject("forecast[0]"));
}

paupulate and forecast=new Forecast() gives mistakes. I know forecast is array but i can not fix